# Creating a updater

Tags: c#

VS 2008 SP1

I have created a application that I have installed on the user computer. However, I want the application to be self-updating. But I am not sure if this would really update the application.

The application will download all the files from the web server, and replace the files in the directory where the program as been installed to. The user will restart the application.

I am just want to be sure, because I can't replace the installed files with the updated ones. As the application will be running. So really the application cannot delete/replace itself.

So, I was thinking that I could download into another directory, if the program is installed in this directory 'program files/application/1.0.0' then I could download the files to 'program files/application/1.0.1'.

However, when the program restarts, how can it know that it has to execute from the 1.0.1 directory?

I can't use clickonce or the updater block for this.

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: ClickOnce has some of these features I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the application with a small loader program which will do a version check. If it's out of date, download the newer binaries and overwrite the old ones. If you want to maintain all version you might end up with:

```
c:\program files\mycompany\myapp\loader (the newer version will point to the latest directory)
c:\program files\mycompany\myapp\v1.0
c:\program files\mycompany\myapp\v1.1
```

If it's on a LAN, you might be able afford the bandwidth of just re-downloading the binaries on start up instead.

Comment: Are there code sample that shows what you meant by wrapper that does version check and self-overwrite?

Comment: Sorry for the uber late reply. A quick example is you write a console application that has a config file that gets updated. It downloads from a central location. That config file can point to a directory and launch the appropriate application. You could make it more intelligent by having to "udpate" (aka delete) older stuff.

Answer (score 3):

A good option is to make an independant Updater application.

The updater will download the newest version and kill/replace the old.

I think this is the best option, because you can execute the updater within the main appication (so you can say that it´s self-updating), or directly by the user with a shortcut.

The updater can check if the application is running and ask the user to exit the application or kill it by itself.

Forgive my english...

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

All of that is already done for you if you use ClickOnce deployment (Project properties, Publish).

Comment: roboUK mentioned that ClickOnce isn't an option.

Comment: For this application, I cannot use clickOnce. Any other ideas would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows Installer for the installation and updating. If you sign your installation packages the user can update your application without needing any administrator privileges.

I've made a website and an application that demonstrates the functionality of what you want on [my website](http://home.scarlet.be/~zippyv/zippydemo/).

Answer (score 1):

Wix Clickthrough might meet your needs: http://wix.sourceforge.net/clickthrough.html

Answer (score 1):

I would look into ClickOnce. It can be configured multiple ways, to check for updates before the application runs, to download from the server each time it's run, or check for updates after the application has started.

I have done ClickOnce Deployment and an independent updating application, they both work well. You obviously will have more flexibility over an updating application that you create yourself, however tho, ClickOnce can also be configured to install prerequisites such as the .NET Framework, Windows Installer, etc... for your application to run.